# Finding number of unique occurrences of text within xml tag in python 2.6

Tags: list, csv, dictionary, xml-parsing, python-2.6

I am trying to find number of unique occurrences of some text within one xml tag and display the same in one of the columns in a csv file.

My Xml file looks somewhat like this:

```
<start>
<tag1> ..... </tag1>
<main> 
<number> 685 </number>
<text> hi..some text...[]para01 |...</text>
</main>
<main> 
<number> 67 </number>
<text> hi..some text...[]para01 |..</text>
</main>
<main> 
<number> 75 </number>
<text> hi..some text...[]para02 |...</text>
</main>
<main> .......
```

I want to find the number of times each text after bracket is occurring (within each main tag), example para01 is seen 2 times, para02 1 time and so on.

What I tried:

```
tree = ET.parse(file)
root=tree.getroot()
with open(csvfile, 'a') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f, delimiter=', ')
    writer.writerow(['number', 'para', 'count'])
    lis = []
    for child in root.findall('main'):
        num = child.find('number').text
        para = re.findall(r"\[] (.*?)\| ", child.find('text').text)
        lis.append("" .join(para))
        res = dict((i, lis.count(i)) for i in lis)
        for key, value in res.items():
           r.append([key, value])
        r = [num, para, [key, value])
        writer.writerow(r)
```

However I seem to be getting result very different from what I want:

```
number   para.     Count
685      para01   para01:2
67       para01   para01:2
75       para02   para02:1
```

What can I change in my code to get the above output?

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the csv aspect, to get to your target rows, try something like this:

```
trgt_txts = root.findall(".//text")
trgt_nums = root.findall(".//number")
txts = []
nums = []
for txt in trgt_txts:
    target = txt.text.split(']')[1].split(' |' )[0]
    txts.append(target)
for n in trgt_nums:
    nums.append(n.text.strip())
for par in set(txts):
    for p,n in zip(txts,nums):
        if p == par:
            print(n,par,par+':'+str(txts.count(par)))
```

Output:

```
75 para02 para02:1
685 para01 para01:2
67 para01 para01:2
```